# SQL WHERE inject 'table.column' into a ? placeholder

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js

I have got the following query running to my database in nodeJS:

```
"SELECT fullName, contacts.email FROM contacts, users WHERE contacts.userID = users.id AND contactType='other'"
```

I would like to do it like below though

```
"SELECT fullName, contacts.email FROM contacts, users WHERE ? AND contactType='other'"
```

And use a data object to fill in the '?' placeholder. However, in the object, I can't state the table.column as I am getting a syntax error because of the fullstop.

Is there any way I can do it so I don't have the tables and the columns in the string as static please?

Comment: Yes, use a stored procedure.

Comment: It's 2022, the ANSI-92 explicit JOIN syntax has been around for `(YEAR(CURDATE() - 1992) as How_Many_Years`, it's long past time you adopted it. 
Bad Habits to Kick : [Using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: You cannot use a column name or table name as a parameter. It would be impossible to compile and optimize the query.

Comment: ok, can you show me how this could change to a JOIN statement please?